# Facebook постинг

Tags: android, facebook

Есть ли простая возможность запостить сообщение фейсбук вызвав его из андроида? Вместе с диалогом авторизации естественно. Может быть есть уже готовые киты? Допустим в iOS все можно сделать через ShareKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Official Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/).

> You can begin integrating the following Facebook Platform features into your Android applications today:
>
> Publishing stories back to Facebook via Feed forms